# Doxygen Error in C

Tags: c++, c, function, warnings, doxygen

What is error in this comment of function in doxygen ?

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///@brief : create_node that will create new node 
///     that can be used by user 
///@param : value:unsigned integer number
///@return : returns newly generated node
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Error :-

warning: The following parameters of create_node(unsigned int value) are not documented:
  parameter 'value'

this warning common for all function in my c file.

warning is there, also it documents the file in proper manner. than why warning ??

Comment: Not really sure but space is causing problem here? Try this _@param : value : unsigned integer number_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try it with:

```
/**
* @brief  create_node that will create new node that can be used by user 
* @param  value:unsigned integer number
* @return  returns newly generated node
*/
```

i never have it problems with this style.